# Navigating with WebBrowser without it being attached to displayed window

Tags: wpf, background, webbrowser-control

I'm using the WebBrowser class from within the WPF framework, I need to do some automated navigation in the background - so I need there to be no visible window for the user.

When navigating with the WebBrowser while not attached to a window, it navigates properly - downloads the content, but never executed the "LoadCompleted" event. I also can not verify that the javascript on the page is being executed.

I can attach the browser to a window as long as there is nothing visible to the user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps, you can use a [WinForms version of `WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't require a container to operate. You can create an instance of WinForm's `WebBrowser` from a WPF app, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured showing an invisible window would work, but its kind of a dirty little hack. If anyone comes up with something better please let me know.

```
        Browser = new WebBrowser();
        var wnd = new Window() //make sure the window is invisible
        {
            Width = 0,
            Height = 0,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            ShowInTaskbar = false,
            ShowActivated = false
        };
        wnd.Content = Browser;
        wnd.Show();
```